# ScrollView not working with SimpleAccordian view/

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I am trying to create an Accordian using the component :  from library:'react-native-simple-accordian'.
But when the number of accordian headers are more I can't see the ScrollView working correctly.

My code:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
        <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                
                        <SimpleAccordion
                            style= {{
                              borderWidth:1,
                              borderRadius:15,
                              margin:3,
                              padding:5,
                              backgroundColor:'#ffffff'
                            }}
                            sections={sectionData}
                            renderHeader= {this.renderHeader}
                            renderContent={this.renderContent}
                            duration={1000}
                            touchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
                            onChange={this.onChangeAccordian.bind(this)}
                            activeSection={this.state.open}
                        />
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
        </View>
```

The styles object is like this:

```
container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
```

What styling or positioning am I doing wrong here for ScrollView?
react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to give style in "contentContainerStyle" prop in case of react-native ScrollView & you may also need to give style property of flexGrow to 1

```
contentContainerStyle = {{
      flexGrow:1
}}
```

Comment: I tried using this : <ScrollView style={{flex:1, }} contentContainerStyle = {{flexGrow:1}} >
But no effect on the result.

Comment: just remove SimpleAccordian view for a moment, and give background color to scrollView and look how much area it's taking, when ScrollView takes full screen then after put back your SimpleAccordian view to it's place